# Admin-reviewed registration in Symfony2 / FosUSerBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I would like to implement the following in my SF2/FOSUserBundle application.

The idea is to have users register themselves using a standard registration form. Then they are sent an email with a confirmation link. When the user opens the link, it validates their email address (important). But I'd like the user to not be enabled yet. It would require the action of an admin to enable the user.

I managed to have the email confirmation part, which is nice, but when the users open the confirmation link they are enabled right away ... Is there a way to change this behaviour.

What would be the best way to do that (I bet i'm not the first one to try) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override default `UserChecker` putting this as parameter:

```
// ACME/YourBundle/Resources/Config/services.yml
parameters:
    security.user_checker.class: ACME\YourBundle\Security\Core\User\UserChecker
```

and write your class:

```
// ACME/YourBundle/Security/Core/User/UserChecker.php
namespace ACME\YourBundle\Security\Core\User\UserChecker;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserChecker as BaseCode;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker extends BaseCode
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // Your Business logic

        parent::checkPreAuth($user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like a nice and clean solution, i'll try that ASAP.

Comment: @skler and if you want to inject a service in your custom user checker? (like the Entity Manager)

Comment: @gp_sflover build your own service as kernel event listener: http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/

Comment: @skler Tx for the reply. I use the InteractiveLoginListener to perform some actions after the user autentication, but if I need to do  some checks "before" granting any autorization to the user?