# FOSUserBundle: registration confirmation by admin only (no email)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, confirmation

*It looks like i'm the only one on the internet to need something like that, i'm out of options to search for a solution to this problem, but i'm sure people here will come to a solution :)*

With FOSUserBundle, i want the following workflow:

1. user fill in the registration form (generated by the bundle)
2. they reach a confirmation page: "thank you, wait for validation by admin"
3. the admin must validate each user by hand (because they have to set up a property on validation)

What i don't want is a confirmation email or any way for the user to validate its account by itself.

I'm aware of this question: [Admin-reviewed registration in Symfony2 / FosUSerBundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25812110/admin-reviewed-registration-in-symfony2-fosuserbundle) but it's a different problem, because the OP uses confirmation emails.

The problem is that i don't see how to **force FOSUserBundle not to enable the user on creation while not activating the confirmation mechanism (token + email)**

Anyone? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to [override FOSUser controller](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md). The page shows exactly the controller you need to edit :)

You will have to :

1. Persist the user with **active set to *false***
2. **Manually set the active flag** of the user **to *true***, with any Admin generator you want (or not).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i already looked that way (though i didn't know about this documentation page, thanks) but i quickly got stuck with the need to override all controller's logic. Scary. However, the event option may be the way to go here, as mentioned in your link. I'll try that and answer my own question if event work, with credits for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could override the user constructor and set the user field 'locked' to true on all new accounts.  Then in your admin section, you can manually edit the user and set it 'locked' to false after you setup the custom property.

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->salt = base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 16, 36);
        $this->enabled = false;
        $this->locked = true;
        $this->expired = false;
        $this->roles = array();
        $this->credentialsExpired = false;
    }
```

Comment: Hi George, unfortunately this approach does not seem to work, as i tried it already. Or i didn't understand something in your answer. But the problem is that FOSUserBundle overrides the value set in the constructor. I may try @palra 's approach.